# Gaussian filter for 1d array pixels

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, neural-network

I'am working on line scan rgb camera trying to remove to noises coming from camera due to intensity variations, to remove that  i chosen gaussian filter to remove the noises and iam having 1d rgb pixels, now **iam stuck in how to generate the standard deviation and kernel size for the gaussian 1d filter**, iam implementing using an verilog programming language and new to the image processing can i help for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your standard deviation should be equal to kernel_size/6 .

if you choose big number for kernel size then your blurry be higher too.

so,you should test some kernel_size then pick the best one .

Comment: Thank you sir.
Now if i choose kernel size = 3 the sigma = 0.5.
in next step i will do convolution with pixel values * gaussian values and i will perform addition for 3 convolution results  then i need to take average or random selects 8 bits in the addition result.

Comment: @manu your well come . if it works for you please vote my answer .